# Can SQLAlchemy Date Time object display local time zone in Flask

Tags: python, flask, utc

This is my first Stackoverflow post, pardon my syntax.
I am trying to have a time stamp in date timestamp without time zone in a SQLAlchemy database display the time in the user's browser with the time in the their timezone, not UTC.

Here is my python/Flask code (I'm a beginner):

## First I query the database

```
    timeclockinfo = TimeClock.query.filter_by(parent_id=current_user.parent_id, user_id=current_user.user_id, closed=1).all()

    #Then I tuple the data
    child_patient = zip(timeclockinfo, user_names, visit_dates )

    #I render the data with Flask
    return render_template('locationcheckinrpt.html', form=form, child_patient=child_patient, timeclockinfo=timeclockinfo, searchForm=searchForm)
    .
    .
    .
    #In the template I have a date time field for the records rendered
    {% for times in child_time %}
          {{  times[0].checkintime.strftime('%Y/%m/%d @ %I:%M %p')    }}
    {% endfor %}
```

Can anyone advise me on how to have the UTC times[0].checkintime display in the browser users timezone and not UTC.

I do have the User enter their time zone so I subtract the appropriate number of hours.

But, I cannot hack my way through getting this to display.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the datetime and the user's time zone, you could create a [template filter](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#registering-filters) that takes a datetime object, does the required computation, and then prints the string.

If your questions is about actually about applying a time zone to a naive datetime object, then take a look at [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) ([relevant section](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic)):

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

tz = timezone('saved_user_timezone')
dt = saved_time_from_db
locl_dt = tz.localize(dt)
```

To display the datetime with the timezone offset, try:

```
local_dt.replace(hour=local_dt.hour + int(local_dt.utcoffset().total_seconds() / 3600))
local_dt.strftime('your format')
```

Comment: Thanks.  That solution works well in the python environment.  My problem is rendering the date for the current timezone in the Flask template on the web.

Comment: That was the perfect solution.   I added the TimeZone to the Users account and it's solved.  Thanks.